# DirectX 9 or 10 Overlay

Tags: c++, directx, overlay, direct3d

How is it possible to draw an overlay over an game with DirectX 9 or 10?

I found code with deprecated DirectShow code, but it will not run.

Comment: Have you had any luck with the link I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you have already found then ignore it, but try this: [Direct3D Hooking Example](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359794)

Comment: I found a proxy D3D9 C++ Project. But your link gives me the right keywords for searching. Thank you! (o: