# DirectDraw Overlays

Tags: graphics, directx, overlay, flicker, directdraw

Does anyone have a working example (code) of a DirectDraw overlay? Like something moving on the screen. I have been trying to find an example of DirectDraw overlaying usage and was unable to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these:

- [from gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359319)
- [from fourcc.org](http://www.fourcc.org/fccovrly.php)

*[Edit]* A bit more googling suggests you might want [D3D Hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421487/directx-9-or-10-overlay)? ..or have your tried [the DirectDraw Overlay Library on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/DirectDrawOverlayLib)?

Comment: I have tried both these sources before, none worked, hence why I asked for a working example.
However thanks for at least trying.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359319

This code should work (I tried it when it comes out and it worked totally fine), its a little old and I don't know if it actually build with the actual SDK thought. (you maybe have to use an old SDK)

Comment: Doesn't work on win7 and I can't figure out, reason why I am asking for a working example is so that I can figure out how directdraw overlays actually work from it.
But thanks.

Comment: http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=282

probably this will be interesting on the changes with windows 7